# Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 - disable angle bracket insertion when autocompleting generic methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Prior to Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, when autocompleting a generic call in a LINQ query against an anonymous type, the IDE did NOT automatically insert <>.  After Update 3, it does.

For example, prior to Update 3, given the following:

```
var myAnonEnumerable = myEnumerable.Select(x=>new { x.Field1, x.Field2 });
```

If I tyen start typing

```
myAnonEnumerable.ToLis
```

When I press <kbd>(</kbd> I would get

```
myAnonEnumerable.ToList()
```

I've grown accustomed to that behavior and rather like it.

After apply Update 3, however, I get

```
myAnonEnumerable.ToList<>()
```

How can I revert to the pre-Update 3 behavior?

Comment: Why did you tag this `n`?

Comment: not intentionally!  Fixed.